# EF Code First: Denormalize Inherited Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, code-first

I have the following entities:

```
Human

-Name

-Age

-Height

-Weight
```

```
SuperHuman : Human

-SuperPower
```

EF is creating the SuperHumans table with only the Power property and when queried joins to the Humans table.  I want all the columns on the SuperHumans table.

Can EF 4.1 Code First be configured to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to configure the SuperHuman to map inherited properties, like so:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SuperHuman>().Map(m => m.MapInheritedProperties());
    {
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't making Human partial work?? If that doesn't work just look into Table-Per-Hierarchy vs Table-Per-Type vs Table-Per-Concrete-Type (TPH, TPT, TPC). You are currently using TPT and you want TPC.

Comment: I want two distinct entities.

Comment: Oh I see. Then put partial and continue using TPT. That should do it, I believe. Although, to be fair, its been a while since I have done this :P. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to make the relationship a Has-a relationship instead of an Is-a relationship.

```
public class SuperHuman
{
    public Human TheHuman { get; set; }
    public string SuperPower { get; set; }
}
```

The resulting database table should have all the fields of Human and SuperHuman (as long as you don't have a separate Human table, in which case a separate Human table will be created, and a Foreign Key will be added to link the tables together.)

Its limited in utility, as it breaks inheritance.  You may find a better solution.

---

Edit:  You could do something like this:

```
public class SuperHuman : Human
{
    public string Name 
    { 
        get { return base.Name; } 
        set { base.Name = value; } 
    }
}
```

---

**Note:** This isn't tested, and may not be the best solution.  I include it here merely as a possible solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do have a Humans table.  I don't mind breaking inheritance in the app.  Good suggestion.